# Facebook php sdk - info not being shown

Tags: facebook, authentication

I downloaded the php sdk from github (link provided from developers.facebook.com). I uploaded the src folder at the root. Now, I pasted the code and replaced the appId and secret with mine. But the page is showing a server error. The following is my code :-

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<title>php-sdk</title>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me. I badly need some help. I cannot find any mistake nor have I modified any part of the code except the app id and the secret. The facebook.php file is in the src folder only. You can find my output at http://beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/login.

Comment: do you have php-curl extension installed

Comment: what is that? Please tell me about that.

Comment: its CURL A command line tool for getting or sending files using URL syntax Read About it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Comment: yes...it is enabled. I found it by the php_info() command at beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/phpinfo

Comment: ok are you sure try the function in my answer if not enable error reporting and see what error it gives.

Comment: ok...let me see...wait a min..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is possibly that you are missing php Curl extension

Facebook PHP SDK Use's Curl To Send Requests.

so First you need to check if the CURL extension is installed at your server

like this

```
function _isCurl(){
    return function_exists('curl_version');
}
```

if not install it and then it will all work

Comment: php curl is installed. I saw it by the php_info() method...It must be some other problem...

Comment: but these at the begining of your php file `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Comment: Still shows curl is installed - the follwing is my code :- <?php
ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
function _isCurl(){
    return function_exists('curl_version');
}
if (_isCurl()) echo "cURL is installed"; else echo "cURL is NOT installed";
?>

Comment: Man at the begining of the php file in your question the facebook test file not Curl test

Comment: I beg your pardon...I did not get you...did you mean me to paste the code in the php file I posted in my question?

Comment: When I pasted the code in my login php file, it shows the message - "Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 6: Couldn't resolve host 'graph.facebook.com' thrown in /home/vol4/byethost8.com/b8_10707526/beta.jokesnfunnypics.com/htdocs/src/base_facebook.php on line 977"

Comment: it may be that your outgoing connections are filtered by the server firewall. Refer to your hosting support for additional information how to allow the connection to external host

Comment: thank you @AboQutiesh - you really helped me. I was trying to build that f-login for about 2 days. You really saved my time...Thank you again. You are a genius in PHP